# Python: select random values for a column from csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem to print random values from a csv for a given column name/index (my second day in Python world :) )

I have so far managed to write the following -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv   # This will help us reading csv formated files.

import random # This will random method

load_file= open('<filename>',"rb")

reader= csv.reader(load_file) #The reader method will put each line
                             # of the csv file into a list of columns

for row in reader:

        from random import shuffle
        shuffle(row[2])

        print row[2]


load_file.close();
```

It is printing a shuffled (random) values from the third column in the file.

objectives -
. define the number of values 1000,2000,50000 etc.
. The values are highly skewed how to ensure uniform distribution ? e.g. if the column has got mostly 0s & few 1s I want to see both values in the output for any sample size.
. write this into a file. (not urgent at this point)

I am using python 2.6.6

Comment: Please move the import statement outside the loop

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it. the program still works but how do I contain the sample size ?

Comment: `row` will be a list of items read from the files. Suppose that row is `[1,2,3,4]` to say `shuffle(row[2])` is to shuffle 1 item; equivalent to shuffling 1 card. So, going back to the list of `[1,2,3,4]` no matter how well you shuffle `row[2]` or `3` it will still be its same original value.

Comment: I may have misled you. Sorry about that. my output is not a list.. rather a single column and all the rows. I just need to print a random sample of this column (not a list as in the example below)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an **unrelated** example to show you how the `shuffle` and `pop` methods can be used:

```
from random import shuffle

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
shuffle(a)
print a
[5,1,4,2,3]
print a.pop()
3
print a
[5,1,4,2]
```

The `pop` method without any arguments deletes the last element from a list and then returns it. However, since you are shuffling the list before hand, you will get a random sequence everytime.

Comment: how to do this for just one column ?
e.g. o/p of my code is 
0
0
0
0
1
0
0

Comment: You create a list of all the values for just that column and then do it.

Comment: for some reason. The website doesn't allow me to type it as a column. I will try your solution. Can you tell me how to contain that list ? e.g. if the column has got 1000 values; I need to print only 100

Comment: You can get only the parts of the list that you want: if column has 1000 values, this gets the first 100: `column = column[:100]

Comment: This might look like a silly question - but how do I create a list for  the values in a column ?
e.g for 
    row[2]
    lines=row[2]  # will this make it a list ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to do this:

1. Read a CSV file with an unknown number of rows;
2. Gather all the items in a given column, say column 2;
3. Choose at random one row from that column.

If that is correct, it is fairly easy to do.

Suppose we have a CSV file like so:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16
```

Usually you would deal with a CSV file row by row. Since you want all the data from a column, you need to read the entire file before you have a set of data you can work with since the total number of rows is not known.

Here is a way:

```
import csv

col=2
with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    data=[row[col] for row in reader]

print data
# ['3', '7', '11', '15']
```

Then if you want a single random number out of that list, use `random.choice(data)`

---

If you want to shuffle all the items in that column, use `random.shuffle(data)` then print it as a column using something like `print '\n'.join(data)` if all the elements of data are strings.

Comment: Thanks dawg. here is the code and the output -
`code`
    import csv   # This will help us reading csv formated files.
    import random # This will random method
    col=2
    with open('/data/internal/skakade/data/MSMgameroom_col.csv','r') as f:
            reader=csv.reader(f)
            data=[row[col] for row in reader]
    from random import shuffle
    shuffle(data)
    print data[:1000]
`code`

output - ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ...'0'] which is great; However, I want to print it as a column, is there a way to that ? Thanks again.

Comment: Either edit your question or ask a new one -- I can't really understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dawg, @sshashank124 and others -

here is the code -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv   # This will help us reading csv formated files.

import random # random method

col=2

with open('<filename>','r') as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        data=[row[col] for row in reader]

from random import shuffle

shuffle(data)

print '\n'.join(data[:100])

f.close();
```

It is giving me output in the form of a column.

I am going to try to write it as a function and add other features next. I might start a separate thread for that.