# How to select a random value from a column in a CSV file in python?

Tags: python, csv, random

So I am able to print out a full column from within a CSV easily with this code:

```
with open("compsci_questions.csv","r") as f:
        if difficulty=="easy":
            csv_reader=csv.reader(f)
            for line in csv_reader:
                print(line[0])
```

Which in turn returns:

```
What is the fastest type of storage?
Which register stores the results of calculations carried out by the ALU?
Which bus sends data to the CPU from the RAM?
What is 10110110 in denary?
What is 7D in denary?
In which topology is each computer connected individually to a central point?
What is half a byte known as?
What is 142 in binary?
What is each column known as in a record?
What is a variable which is available anywhere in a program known as?
```

How would I get it to randomly select just one of those questions as well as selecting the column?

Comment: Use random function to generate the index within the limits

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827806/python-select-random-values-for-a-column-from-csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to get a random row in your csv like:

#### Code:

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(data)
questions = list(csv_reader)
random_question = random.choice(questions)
```

Note that this will return a list corresponds to the csv row.  To get a specific column, you can then select like:

```
text = random_question[column_needed]
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = StringIO(u"""What is the fastest type of storage?
Which register stores the results of calculations carried out by the ALU?
Which bus sends data to the CPU from the RAM?
What is 10110110 in denary?
What is 7D in denary?
In which topology is each computer connected individually to a central point?
What is half a byte known as?
What is 142 in binary?
What is each column known as in a record?
What is a variable which is available anywhere in a program known as?""")

import random
import csv
csv_reader = csv.reader(data)
questions = list(csv_reader)
random_question = random.choice(questions)
print(random_question)
```

#### Results:

```
['What is 142 in binary?']
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this and it completely answers what I asked for, but if I want to repeat this sequence 5 times (as I need the code to ask 5 questions), it gives me the error `IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you use the line `questions = list(csv_reader)`?  That step empties the reader into a structure that can be interrogated more than once.

Comment: Aha! I did use that line but it turns out I just put the `for i in range(5):` in the wrong place. Thanks for the help.